# Multi-(programming)-language tokenization

Tags: parsing, token, tokenize, multilingual

Is there a tool (or the like) which does multi (programming) language tokenization? So input should be a source code file, the tool should then auto detect the language, tokenize the file and output the tokens as xml/json/..

Comment: And if you had such a tool, what would you do with the result?

Comment: In short no... because the theory is that detecting a swap of grammar is just as complicated as the individual language components. So you've two options, either combine the grammar of the two languages in one file ...or if the separation between the two languages is "obvious" enough, load the two grammars separately and have some of your own code switch between the two as needed.

Comment: Let me change my question.  I know of a tool that can lex dozens of langauges in a similar way.   It doesn't decide which file/which language; that has to happen outside the lexing process.

Comment: Combining "two parsers" into one may not tell you enough.   C++ and Java both have keywords  "if", "else', operators "++", "--",  identifiers spelled similarly,   You almost have to parse to distinguish which file is which language.

Comment: I need it for analysing code in an educational project. There are an unknown number of implementations of the same feature(s) in different programming languages and styles which must be automatically analysed in terms of NCLOC and other metrics. 
A standard code metrics tool isn't enough here, because I need the metrics for separate functions/methods and not for whole files.
If you know a metrics tool wich can do that, that would be just as fine as a multi language tokenizer.